# Redirect URL to different directory using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url, redirect

In our previous site, articles didn't have categories included in the URL (ex. example.com/page-name), but now we have a new site, we changed how our URLs work and added a category in it (ex. newexample.com/category-1/page-name).

Is there a way for htaccess to have the old URL with the new domain (ex. newexample.com/page-name) be redirected to its correct URL with the category (ex. newexample.com/category-1/page-name)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category-1/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Would that work if the category it belongs to is a different one?

Comment: It won't - this simply redirects everything to category-1. If you need to do more you'll have to specify different conditions

Comment: oh i see. so there isn't a way to have htaccess look for which category it belongs to then redirect it there? is that possible with PHP though?

Comment: @ZackHowler if you have some regex conditions to determine the category based on the URL structure then it can be done right here by altering the match condition `^(.*)$`

Comment: that's probably going to be a problem, seeing that the original URL we're trying to retrieve doesn't have any categories in it